# How to disable all input when checkbox is checked on load with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want the `input` each `tr` disabled if its `checkbox` is unchecked - on page load. As I understand, I have to call a function to check if the `checkbox` was checked. But as my code below, it's not working.

```js
$(function() {
  fn_chkBox('.form-check-input'); //see if checked on load
  function fn_chkBox() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).closest("tr").find("input.form-control").prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
      $(this).closest("tr").find("input.form-control").prop("disabled", true);
    }
  }
});

$(".form-check-input").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest("tr").find("input.form-control").prop("disabled", false);
  } else { //unchecked
    $(this).closest("tr").find("input.form-control").prop("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Day</th>
    <th>Fish</th>
    <th>Crab</th>
    <th>Shrimp</th>
    <th>Squid</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="mon" value="1" checked/> Mon</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mon[1]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mon[2]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mon[3]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mon[4]" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="tue" value="1" /> Tue</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="tue[1]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="tue[2]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="tue[3]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="tue[4]" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="wed" value="1" /> Wed</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="wed[1]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="wed[2]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="wed[3]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="wed[4]" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want all the `input` in each row `tr` disabled when load if its `checkbox` is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.form-check-input:not(:checked)` selector to select all checkboxes that are not checked.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.form-check-input:not(:checked)').closest("tr").find("input.form-control").prop("disabled", true);
});

$(".form-check-input").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest("tr").find("input.form-control").prop("disabled", false);
  } else { //unchecked
    $(this).closest("tr").find("input.form-control").prop("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Day</th>
    <th>Fish</th>
    <th>Crab</th>
    <th>Shrimp</th>
    <th>Squid</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="mon" value="1" checked/> Mon</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mon[1]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mon[2]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mon[3]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mon[4]" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="tue" value="1" /> Tue</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="tue[1]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="tue[2]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="tue[3]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="tue[4]" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="wed" value="1" /> Wed</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="wed[1]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="wed[2]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="wed[3]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="wed[4]" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

To do what you require you can simply `trigger()` your `change` event handler on the checkboxes when the page loads.

Two other things to note here. Firstly, the logic there can be simplified by providing the inverse `checked` property state to the `prop('disabled')` call. Secondly, be careful when placing your event handlers outside document.ready. If you've put the jQuery code in the `head` of the page you encounter issues with the event not being bound.

With all that said, try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $(".form-check-input").on('change', e => {
    $(e.target).closest('tr').find('input.form-control').prop('disabled', !e.target.checked);
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

```css
.form-control { width: 50px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Day</th>
    <th>Fish</th>
    <th>Crab</th>
    <th>Shrimp</th>
    <th>Squid</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="mon" value="1" checked/> Mon</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mon[1]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mon[2]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mon[3]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mon[4]" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="tue" value="1" /> Tue</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="tue[1]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="tue[2]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="tue[3]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="tue[4]" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="wed" value="1" /> Wed</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="wed[1]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="wed[2]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="wed[3]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="wed[4]" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage your existing function and just trigger a 'change' event on load. You can also shorten your function by setting disabled to `!$(this).is(':checked')`

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').trigger('change')
});

$(".form-check-input").change(function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").find("input.form-control").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Day</th>
    <th>Fish</th>
    <th>Crab</th>
    <th>Shrimp</th>
    <th>Squid</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="mon" value="1" checked/> Mon</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mon[1]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mon[2]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mon[3]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mon[4]" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="tue" value="1" /> Tue</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="tue[1]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="tue[2]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="tue[3]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="tue[4]" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="wed" value="1" /> Wed</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="wed[1]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="wed[2]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="wed[3]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="wed[4]" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```